# Probability: problem with 300 balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are **300 white balls** inside a box. We are **drawing randomly** **100 balls from inside of the box**, and we **paint those 100 balls with a black color** and then we **put them back in the box**. Afterwards, we are **drawing again randomly 100 from inside of the box**. What's the **probability** of getting **exact 10 black balls** the last time we draw 100 balls?

I really couldn't think of some solution to this, it seems quite different from what i have already solved in probability problems.

Comment: This looks hypergeometric

Comment: Have not solved yet problems like: $n$ balls are there of which $w$ are white and $b$ are black. What is the probability of getting exactly $k$ black balls when $m$ balls are drawn? Here $n=300$, $w=200$, $b=100=m$ and $k=10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- the ways to select 100 balls are $\binom{300}{100}$
- the ways to select 10 black balls among the 100 black balls are $\binom{100}{10}$
- the ways to select the others $100-10$ not black balls among the others 200
  balls are $\binom{200}{90}$

Comment: "...the ways to select the others 100−10 black balls..." Is the word "black" correct in this place?

Comment: @user thanks I fix the typo!